# How can I handle an Empty String when saving to integer database base column

Tags: c#

I have an aspx web application that records data into database.
I used this C# code to write my data which comes from an HTML 5 Input control into the SQL Table column that is an integer.

```
ca.TCDCount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inpTCDCount.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(inpTCDCount.Value) : 0;
```

And that works BUT when I am editing a record in the ASP.net application I do not want to see those zeros.  If the data column value is equal to zero I want my Input Control value to be an Empty String.

How can I write an inline if statement to set the value of my HTML5 Input to an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

You have two general ways to fix this problem:

- **Make your integer column in the database nullable** - this is the proper way of fixing the problem of distinguishing zeros from no-entry. `TdCount` would become `int?`, and the code for reading and writing the DB would need to account for `DBNull`s
- **Pick a prohibited value and use it as an indicator of no-entry** - this inferior approach should be used only when you cannot modify the database schema. In this case your C# model would still add nullability to `TdCount`, but the value that you write to the database would be an integer that you picked to be your null indicator (when the data is expected to be positive, a `-1` is a common choice for a "no-value" indicator).